# Do pilots pilots keep track of their groundspeed, by head?

Tags: navigation

For VFR nav. flights, do pilots have to keep track of their groundspeed, by head (done so by considering wind speed, wind direction, crosswind, tailwind etc.)?

And the purpose of this, is to check that you are on par with your pre-planned flying time?

Comment: Not really, usually we just keep track of time at waypoints and calculate the average groundspeed between segments, provided you aren't using a GPS with that capability.

Comment: Not really possible to give a definitive answer.  Depends on personality/flying style (some people like electronic aides, and even use them in their cars), what you're flying, how familiar you are with the route, and probably a bunch of other factors.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what you have in the cockpit, most planes these days fly with some kind of GPS be it a [full blown panel mounted IFR certified unit](https://buy.garmin.com/en-US/US/cInTheAir-c582-p1.html) or just an [iPhone app](https://foreflight.com/). All of the ones I have encountered either by default or with minimal effort will display your ground speed for you and there is really no need to manually compute it.

The main purpose of ground speed is to ensure that you actually arrive at your destination with more than vapors in your tank. Let's say you need to travel 100 nautical miles in a [Cherokee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piper_PA-28_Cherokee). You have 1.5 hours of fuel on board which is legal for a VFR flight. You unexpectedly hit a 55 Kt headwind at altitude. You trip is now going to take you a little over 2 hours assuming you cruise out at 100 Kts/Hour. Knowing your ground speed ensures you have the information you need to know that you will need to land ~50 miles into the flight and gas up.

When flying IFR its also important so that you can provide ATC an appropriate time deviation if you are not going to make a way point when expected.

On a similar note, [most decent flying apps](https://foreflight.com/) will do fuel computations en route for you as long as you provide a performance profile.